# Java Graphics2D. Drawing scaled image on a retina display

Tags: java, awt, retina-display, graphics2d

I'm creating a 64x64 pixels `VolitileImage`, drawing some images and shapes on it (using `drawImage`, `fillRect` etc.), then I want to draw this image stretched up to 640x640 pixels. I expect to see the 64x64 matrix of 10x10 screen pixels squares. That's what I see on non-retina display. But when I try this on a retina-display I actually see 128x128 matrix of 5x5 squares.

Here's what I'm talking about:
[image: non-retina and retina behavior]

Is there a way of "turning off" this behavior? Because what I need is to display 64x64 image stretched 10 times.

**UPD**:
Adding an compileable example: https://gist.github.com/miriti/651cb4b768cc5a076341

Each balack and white point is 1 pixel in a 64x64 image. Notice the difference between regular display and retina:

[image]

Comment: for better help sooner post an SSCCE / MCVE, short, runnable, compilable,

Comment: For some reason, at least for browsers, it seems that when you want to display an image of a x b size on retina display, you should display it in 2a x 2b size.

Comment: @LajosArpad any suggestions how to fight it?

Comment: The right half of the red circle image can only look that way if it was painted at double resolution; therefore I conclude that its your use of VolatileImage that causes the artifacts. Use a BufferedImage instead.

Comment: @Durandal interesting! BufferedImage indeed does the trick. But I still hope to do it with VolatileImage because I need GPU performance.. Probably I could try to draw BufferedImage on VolileImage..

Comment: I'd avoid the extra complications of VolatileImage until you actually run into real world performance issues. BufferedImage is potentially hardware accelerated (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#setAccelerationPriority-float- ). BufferedImage inherits this method. Depending on what you ultimately want to do, it may be advantagous to upscale the image once and use the upscaled version to fill the window (if the upscale can be reused many times).

Comment: @Durandal thank you! I'm sure I can go with BufferedImage.